# Why does texture fades away on the surface?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

[image]

So I was making an interior scene and when I added the floor texture I got this:

[image]

I used a node setup that BlenderGuru uses so I don't know if it's because of the HDRI or something else. I first thought that the plane was too big and was out of my view so I made it smaller. But that did not fix the problem.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Could you post your material node setup for the floor?

Comment: I just did ! :)

Comment: Check if it's not z-fighting, so make sure it's the only one plane there.

Comment: It was not z-fighting but i just discovered the plane had to be flipped -_- lol.Thanks for the reply though !

Answer (score 1):

The plane's texture was fading on my screen (The right one) the left one is how it should be. : [image]
And that is because a plane has 2 different sides one that is made to be facing the camera (Left one) and the other side has to be facing away from the camera (right one).[image]
Now to fix this problem you need to select the face that is facing the wrong way in edit mode (The right one) then press ctrl + f and click on flip normals.

That will make sure that the face is facing the right direction and then you won't get the fading effect.

I would explain it better with pictures but I can't because I don't have more than 10 reputation points.